# python - extracting repeated words from webpage and removing stopwords

Tags: python, dataframe

I was trying to remove stop words from a webpage after I count the frequency of the words in it. The following is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

stop = stopwords.words('english')
Website1 = requests.get("http://www.nerdwallet.com/the-best-credit-cards")
soup = BeautifulSoup(Website1.content)
texts = soup.findAll(text=True)
a = Counter([x.lower() for y in texts for x in y.split()])
b = (a.most_common())
makeaframe = pd.DataFrame(b)
makeaframe.columns = ['Words', 'Frequency']
print (makeaframe) --------1
makeaframe['Words']=makeaframe['Words'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in stop])
print(makeaframe) ----------2
```

at point 1 I get an output as which is ok for me:

```
     Words  Frequency
0     the        412
1     on        386
2     and        368
3     for        364
4     credit     340
5     a        335
6     to        295
7     card        269
```

now after point 1 I tried removing the stopwords and I was expecting the following:

```
     Words  Frequency
4     credit     340
7     card        269
```

But, instead I get:

```
    Words  Frequency
0   [h, e]        412
1   [n]        386
2   [n]        368
3   [f, r]        364
4   [c, r, e]        340
5   []        335
6   []        295
7   [c, r]        269
```

I guess the lambda function was reading letter by letter and remvoing the stop words and then I tried the following functions and couldnt get through..

```
#print makeaframe.ix[:,'Words'].apply(lambda Words: [for Words not in stop])
#print makeaframe.ix[:,'Words'].apply(lambda Words: [item for item in Words if item not in stop])
#makeaframe['Words']=[word for word in makeaframe['Words'] if word not in stop]
```

I browsed the internet to get through this problem but couldnt find a solution.. please help

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create the list as simply as:

```
resultwords = [word for word in querywords if word.lower() not in stopwords]
result = ' '.join(resultwords)

final = Counter(resultwords)
print final
```

From there, I think you can quite easily transform into JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your example you will get desired output:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize,sent_tokenize
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import re
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen("http://www.nerdwallet.com/the-best-credit-cards"))

#To remove punctuation and number

word = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]"," ",soup.getText())
#extract words
words = word_tokenize(word)
#remove stop words
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
filtered_words = [w for w in words if not w in stop_words]
a = Counter([x.lower() for y in filtered_words for x in y.split()])
b = (a.most_common())
makeaframe = pd.DataFrame(b)
makeaframe.columns = ['Words', 'Frequency']
makeaframe.head()
```

the output is

```
     Words  Frequency
 0   credit        389
 1     card        332
 2  rewards        257
 3        i        245
 4        e        225
```